# Count Number of hours between a range SQL

Tags: sql, date, ssms

Im trying to count the number of working hours from some users for the month, the only way to do it is to see the date and hour for the productions entries they made. so I got:

```
Select  a.EmployeeID, cast(a.fDate as Date) fDate, datepart(HOUR, a.fDate) fHour
From Table 
Group by a.EmployeeID, cast(a.fDate as Date), datepart(HOUR, a.fDate)
```

This gives me the detail by date of the hours production was done, however I would like to know the total of hours in that time frame. For example:

[image: Current Results]

I know employee xxx on 09/01/2018 registered production at 10:00AM, 11:00AM 12:00PM and 1:00PM, so the result will be 4 hours. Every employee has different working days so thats the only way I think I can calculated this...

Help?

Comment: So for every record on a day, you want to count 1 hour? And then sum that up for a month?

Comment: yes, I want to count the number of working hours by day, 09/01/2018 4 hours, 09/02/2018 6 hours, etc. I dont care about the detail just the total

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the DATEDIFF of the min and max of fDate, group by EmployeeId and Date of a.fDate?

For example:

```
Select  a.EmployeeID, cast(a.fDate as Date) as fDate, min(a.fDate) as TimeIn, max(a.fDate) as TimeOut, (DATEDIFF(mi, min(a.fDate), max(a.fDate)) / 60) as Hours
From MyTable a
Group by a.EmployeeID, cast(a.fDate as Date)
```

Comment: Happy to help.  To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from grayed out to filled in. You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.